# Data received by my HC-05/Arduino Uno from MATLAB Bluetooth is in a strange format or the setup is incorrect

Tags: matlab, bluetooth, arduino, uart, hc-05

I am trying to use MATLAB's bluetooth object to connect to my [HC-05](https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/BlueTooth-HC05-HC06-Modules-How-To) (connected to Arduino Uno by Serial) and send it strings ('1','2',etc).  However, the issue is that when the data arrives it is in a strange format, and it seems like different inputs from MATLAB can give the same output in the HC05.  Here is my problematic output:[image] And here is the code I'm using:

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
mySerial.begin(38400);
}

void loop() {

        if (mySerial.available()) {
                // read the incoming byte:
                int c = mySerial.read();
                Serial.println(c);
                //Serial.println(c);

        }


}
```

I've tried different baud rates for the software serial and switching the TX/RX wires.  Also different println formats. The output just always seems odd no matter what format I put it in. **Any idea what could be the problem?**

Comment: - You send them as strings, and read them as ints. And you forget the terminator.

Comment: Alright, I tried sending them as ints but maybe I didnt really define the data types correctly. And what is the terminator in this case? Is it in the string/after the int or?